# Syncing analog rytm MKII with analog four MKI

Tags: midi, synthesizer

I want to sync. both synth. Here my set up:

Connect MIDI OUT of AR to MIDI IN of AF.

On the AR:

set OUT PORT FUNC to “MIDI” and OUTPUT TO to “MIDI” in the GLOBAL > MIDI CONFIG > MIDI PORT CONFIG menu.

activate CLOCK SEND and TRANSPORT SEND in the GLOBAL > MIDI CONFIG > MIDI SYNC menu.

On the AF:

set INPUT FROM to “MIDI” in the GLOBAL > MIDI CONFIG > MIDI PORT CONFIG menu.

activate CLOCK RECEIVE and TRANSPORT RECEIVE in the GLOBAL > MIDI CONFIG > MIDI SYNC menu.

the sync is working fine, but I don’t want a master / slave, just sync, and now some tracks ON / OFF of the Analog Rytm MKII controls also of the Elektron Analog Four MKI. Is it posible to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the AR MkII, set MUTE DEST to “INT” in the GLOBAL > MIDI CONFIG > PORT CONFIG menu. 
On the AR MkII, disactivate TRANSPORT SEND in the GLOBAL > MIDI CONFIG > SYNC mENU